# Java json exception

Tags: java, json

Using this code to call steam api. Parsing json gives me some problems. I manage to print the json in the console, accessing furhter data fails. Here is my code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXX&steamids=XXXXXXX"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
System.out.println(json.get("response")); >>> (1)
int out = json.getJSONObject("players").getInt("steamid");
System.out.println(out);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["players"] not found.
```

```
{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "XXXXX",
                "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
                "profilestate": 1,
                "personaname": "XXXXX",
                "lastlogoff": 123123,
                "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/XXX/",
                "avatar": "XXXXX",
                "avatarmedium": "XXXX",
                "avatarfull": "XXXXX",
                "personastate": 1,
                "primaryclanid": "XXX",
                "timecreated": XXX,
                "personastateflags": 0,
                "gameextrainfo": "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege",
                "gameid": "359550"
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

Comment: players is a JSONArray not JSONObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to understand the difference between **JSONObject** structure and **JSONArray** structure

The JSONObject will starts with **"{"**, and JSONArray starts with **"["**.

I just noticed your mistake, you didnt assign **json.get("response")**  to any variable.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXX&steamids=XXXXXXX"), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            System.out.println(json.get("response"));
        JSONObject playersJson=json.get("response");
        int out = playersJson.getJSONArray("players").getJSONObject(0).getInt("steamid");
```

So try changing your code as above.

Comment: Thank you taking your time. It still gives me an error -  JSONObject["players"] not found.

Comment: did you try changing the code ? based on above

Comment: Yes I copied your code above and changed the URL to the correct one

Comment: @piguy try now, i missed your mistake, you didnt assign json.get("response") to any variable.

Comment: I had to cast (JSONObject) json.get("response"); and its working now. I see my mistake. Thank you for helping a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `players` is not a `JSONObject`, it's a `JSONArray` which contains `JSONObject`s. In this case, `players` contains one `JSONObject`, so you need to access that object first using `players[0]`:

```
int out = json.getJSONArray("players")[0].getInt("steamid");
```

Comment: Thank you taking your time! It gives me an error - The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray